# Finding average word length in a given year

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, hash-map

I have written a function which takes the year in question and words as a data which is a dictionary that maps words to the list of year/count. Now I am wondering how I can improve the code that I have or how to make it more simpler or make it better performance-wise.

```
def avgWordLen(year, words):
    totLen = 0
    totword = 0
    for word in words:
        for nary in words[word]:
            if nary.year == year:
                totLen += len(word) * nary.count
                totword += nary.count
    if totword != 0:
        return totLen / totword
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`totword` and `totLen` are not so good names.
And in any case [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests to use `snake_case` for both variable and function names. So I recommend the following renames:

- `total_word_length` instead of `totLen`
- `word_count` instead of `totword`
- `average_word_length` instead of `avgWordLen`

When you iterate over keys in a dictionary and then lookup the values in every iteration step,
then it's better to iterate over the dictionary *items*.
That is, instead of:

> ```
>     for word in words:
>         for nary in words[word]:
> ```

Do like this:

```
    for word, nary_list in words.items():
        for nary in nary_list:
```

This way you avoid unnecessary dictionary lookups.

At the end of the method, the `else` is unnecessary,
because the `if` part always returns.
It's slightly simpler this way:

```
    if word_count != 0:
        return total_word_length / word_count
    return 0
```